# getting this message when i try to update from a terminal

Tags: updates, downloads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix a 404 Error using a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa)

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jsevi83/unity/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jsevi83/unity/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I get this at the end of trying to update. HELP!

Answer (score 1):

It's look like your URL doesn't exist anymore. That's why APT give you this message. 
Try to locate the new PPA and replace it.

EDIT : By looking the launchpad of jsevi83, I've found that the address of his PPA is ppa:jsevi83/precise